# How Do I Select a Block of HTML in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

The code that I want to select is on two lines. Like this:

```
<div id="gsContent">
<div class="gbBlock gcBackground1">
```

In particular I am trying to select and remove this piece of code. At first I would just like to select it, but can not get it working and I am trying since a couple of hours with different methods...

I've tried selecting the block with this SQL query, but it's not working.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '<div id="gsContent">
<div class="gbBlock gcBackground1">';
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%<div id="gsContent"><div class="gbBlock gcBackground1">%';` should work.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I've tried it with % as well before and I get the same result.  MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 6.0282 seconds.)

Comment: did you check, that it is part of the post_content, and not just the templates?

Comment: Yes, see screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/QqoIzEW.png (even if I put it in the firefox browser search it finds it and higlights it)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching for complete html a better way is to search for some parts 
SELECT * FROM [table name] WHERE [column name] LIKE '%%';